# Processwire multiple-site with multiple databases: fields synchronization

Tags: multisite, processwire

Does anyone have ideas or solutions for synchronizing fields and modules between multisite instances?

Fields can be exported in the form of a JSON from one instance and re-imported in the other. This is a bit more difficult for modules.

I will develop something to simplify the process, but maybe there are already projects I can build on or help.

Answer (score 2):

One of the most common ways is to user the [Migrations](https://lostkobrakai.github.io/Migrations/) module. Then rather than adding yourself the fields/templates/modules, yo do that with the API and run the migration file on every site you want the updates.

I've always though that you could probably track this changes and save them with hooks on the API calls that save fields/templates/modules but I haven't seen anything that attempts this.

Comment: Thanks elabx, this is a nice suggestion. I try it and i will give you a Feedback. Merci